# updating gridview using multiple values in datakeynames

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to execute an update command via gridview using datakeynames.

I have the following code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sqlProductlist" DataKeyNames="product_id,price_id,value" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="product_id" HeaderText="product_id" SortExpression="product_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="price_id" HeaderText="price_id" SortExpression="price_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="description" SortExpression="description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="value" HeaderText="value" SortExpression="value" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="extra_value" HeaderText="extra_value" SortExpression="extra_value" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlProductlist" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_connectionstring%>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT p.product_id, pr.price_id, p.name, p.description, pr.name AS type, pp.value, pp.extra_value FROM dbo.price AS pr INNER JOIN dbo.price_product AS pp ON pr.price_id = pp.price_id INNER JOIN dbo.product AS p ON pp.product_id = p.product_id WHERE (p.main_product_id = @main_product_id)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE dbo.price_product SET value = @value WHERE product_id = @product_id AND price_id = @price_id">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlMainProduct" Name="main_product_id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="value" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="product_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="price_id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I want to do is update the "value" field of one line using product_id & price_id from the gridview and use it in the where clausule. Is this possible with Datakeynames? The code I am using is not working and giving no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's Possible....

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string product_id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    string price_id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
    string value = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString(); //Here you will get the datakeys value 

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");//Put Your Sql connection
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("update YourTableName set value='" + value + "' where product_id='" + product_id + "' and price_id='" + price_id + "'", conn);
    da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bindgrid(); // Again bind the Same gridview
}
```